# Conemu disable hotkeys

Tags: conemu

Conemu is taking a lot of hotkeys which are used in other programs, such as Ctr+` in Sublime which activates the console.

I don't want any Conemu hotkeys, how do I disable them all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working with terminal without any hotkeys? Strange decision.

Just go to Keys&Macro and disable them. Can't see any problem.

Comment: ah, after reading this I realized that only the "global" hotkeys run system wide. I'll just disable the global ones so they don't interfere with sublime!

Comment: Let say that I have CTRL+LEFT, CTRL+RIGHT as VIM keybind. Since it's system hotkeys it's impossible to unbind it.

Comment: @Kursion Read carefully Ctrl+Left/Right descriptions. These are not hotkeys you are looking for.

Comment: This again got me after years. Had to click tree parent to see settings.